# Why isn't the prepopulated table data not showing in production (through play store download) yet it shows on apk sent to device?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm created a simple to do list. I have a default category called "All" that I prepopulate into the db like this

```
return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app,
            ListDatabase::class.java,
            ListDatabase.DATABASE_NAME,
        )
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    val contentValues = ContentValues()
                    contentValues.put ("id",1)
                    contentValues.put ("name","All")
                    db.insert("Category", OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, contentValues)
                }
            })
            .build()
```

When using the app on an emulator or through USB on my Samsung and Huawei, the default category shows up
[image]

However, when I download the app on play store, the default category doesn't show up even though I know it was prepopulated successfully since the home screen reflects that the main category is "All"

[image]

I suspected that the problem may be how I fetch the categories from the database but I'm not sure

```
    private fun getAllCategories() {
        getCategoriesJob?.cancel()
        getCategoriesJob = listUseCases
            .categoryGetAll()
            .onEach { listOfCategories ->
                _mainUIState.value = mainUIState.value.copy(
                    categories = listOfCategories
                )
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

A long term solution to ask for is, is there a way to test how an app will behave when downloaded from play store. I've also looked into proguard rules but I'm not sure if there is any rule I should change to fix this issue